# Can clone humans have children?

Tags: clones, oblivion

In the movie of '[Oblivion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivion_(2013_film))' Jack Harper and Victoria Olsen are clones of their former self. It isn't shown in the movie that if they can have a baby together but if we assume that there can be cloned humans, **Can they reproduce or they will be sterile?**

Comment: There can be cloned humans, cloning is fairly simple at its most basic.  Cloning fully grown individuals with memories intact however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normal clones are the same as any other biological entity, so as long as there is no genetic defect leading to sterilization, then a clone would be able to reproduce naturally.

However in the context of the movie, we don't know what kind of technology the Tet used to clone them; it can be inferred that some form of accelerated aging is used, which may damage the reproduction ability. Further, its likely that the Tet would sterilize its clones as a matter of course.

Answer (score 6):

From the film Oblivion it is apparent that Jack-49 is fertile as he is the father of Julia's daughter.

Comment: Hi, I saw it too but the female person was Julia (a normal human), so could Victoria have that condition?

Comment: @S.GOLIZADEH it is impossible to draw any conclusions about Victoria's fertility status from the information available in the film.